# Raspberry Pi 1.2 GHz kernel panic

Tags: kernel, overclocking

When I overclock my Raspberry Pi B+ to 1200 MHz, it spits out a nasty kernel panic, even though it is overvolted and cooled sufficiently. However, on my Raspberry Pi Model B, I have gone past 1.3 GHz. What is the problem here?

Comment: The possibility of overclocking exists because all "identical" chips cannot be made equal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_binning#Definition If they were all guaranteed to do it, they would just sell it as a 1.2 Ghz processor in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is a lack of understanding on your part.

If overclocking works its is a bonus.  There are no guarantees.

It depends on the luck of the draw as to whether the silicon you actually have is good enough to overclock to any particular value.

Comment: Then how did AMD overclock their AMD FX to 8.429 GHz?(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKN4VMOenNM) Surely that processor did not just have _really, really_ good silicon...

Comment: @LiamSchumm - Very good silicon + insanely low temps + **a really good mobo** + disabling all but a single core.